# Fortran/MPI: Is it possible to declare a variable on a single processor only?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

Lets say something like:

if (proc.eq.0) double precision :: B(n)

so that it declares array B on proc 0 only. I know this is not allowed, it's just by way of example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, generelly it is not possible to put a variable declaration into an `if` clause. However, if your master and slave processes are doing completely different things and requiring therefore completely different variable declarations, you can use different routines for their work:

```
if (proc == 0) then
    call proc_master()
else
    call proc_slave()
end if
```

The routine `proc_master()` can declare all variables needed for the master process and all the instructions master should execute, while `proc_slave()` would do the same for the slaves.

If the difference in the codes for the slaves and master is only slight, you could use allocatable variables and allocate only in the appropriate processes:

```
integer, allocatable :: bigarray(:,:)

:
if (proc == 0) then
    allocate(bigarray(nn, nn))
end if
```

If the difference in the codes for master and the slaves is even less (e.g. just a few scalar variables as in your example) then just leave it. You definietly should not worry about the few bytes you loose due to the superfluous variables.